# Problem with filtering the elements from the database with the mat-select dropdown

Tags: c#, html, angular, filter

I have the problem with filtering elements from the database. I think that I miss some call of filter function in the html but I am not sure. The files are represented below. Thanks

html file......................................

```
  <mat-form-field apperance="outline">
    <mat-label>Odaberi vrstu događaja</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="event">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let eventType of eventTypes" [value]="eventType.Id">
        {{ eventType.Name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

ts file.........................................................

```
export class FilterEventsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private eventsService: EventsService,
    private eventTypeService: EventTypesService,
  ) {}
  
  form: FormGroup;

  eventTypes: eventTypeDTO[];
  events: eventDTO[];
  //eventCities: cityDTO[];
  initialFormValues: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
//      title: '',
  //    city: '',
      event: '',
      //dateOfEvent: Date,
    });

    this.initialFormValues = this.form.valueChanges;

    this.eventTypeService.getAllEventTypes().subscribe((eventTypes) => {
      this.filterEvents(this.form.value);
      this.eventTypes = eventTypes;
      console.log(this.eventTypes);
      this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((values) => {
        console.log(values);

        this.filterEvents(values);
      });
    });
  }

  filterEvents(values: any) {
    this.eventsService
      .filter(values)
      .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<eventDTO[]>) => {
        this.events = response.body;
      });
  }
}
```

service.ts file.............................................

```
  public filter(values: any): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: values });
    return this.http.get<eventDTO[]>(`${this.apiURL}/filter`, {
      params,
      observe: 'response',
    });
  }
```

backend... controller...................................................................

```
[HttpGet("filter")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<EventDTO>>> Filter([FromQuery] FilterEventsDTO filterEventsDTO)
    {
        var eventsQueryable = context.Event.AsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterEventsDTO.Title))  ///ako string nije prazan, znaci ako je unesen
        {
            eventsQueryable = eventsQueryable.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(filterEventsDTO.Title));
        }
        if(filterEventsDTO.EventTypeId != 0) ///ako id nije 0, znaci ako je odabrano nesta
        {
            eventsQueryable = eventsQueryable.Where(x => x.EventAndEventTypes.Select(y => y.EventTypeId).Contains(filterEventsDTO.EventTypeId));
        }
        var events = await eventsQueryable.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToListAsync();
        return mapper.Map<List<EventDTO>>(events);
    }
```

Comment: The first thing would be to isolate the problem. Is the problem in the Angular UI or in the API? You can try the following steps: is the request sent to the API (see DevTools)? Can you put a breakpoint in the API method `FilterEventsDTO` and check what parameters are transmitted? Which data are expected for the parameters and which data is returned?

Comment: I am getting only the title from the query, but the 'EventTypeId' is null, it's not retrieving the data selected from the dropdown.